# Javascript - How to get an array of indexes of all matches of a RegExp against a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this simple problem, and I want a simple solution, if it exists.

Suppose I have the following string:

```
var myString = "IS is iS Is";  
var myArray = [];
```

I want to get an array of size 4, where:

```
myArray[0] = 0;  
myArray[1] = 3;  
myArray[2] = 6;  
myArray[3] = 9;
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: var myArray = [0,3,6,9] fits your stated problem, though I don't know what myString has got to do with it.

Comment: @MarkFisher He wants to get the indexes to each of regex matches.

Comment: @Nit yes I know, i was pointing out he hasn't stated a requirement between the string and the array. I could infer what it is, but my solution still fits his stated problem which was an array size four with values 0,3,6,9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can;

```js
var myString = "IS is iS Is";  
var myArray = []; 

var re = /\b(is)\b/ig;

match = re.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    myArray.push(match.index);
    match = re.exec(myString);
}

document.write(myArray);
```